# cannot reference 'method' before superconstructor has been called

Tags: java, oop, methods, super

Lets say I have couple of classes and I am trying to call one of the methods in my super class and this error happens. I am not able to understand why?

File1:

```
public class A extends B {
   public A(int arg1){
       this(arg1, new class_C(getMethod()));  // Throws error here
   }
   public A(int arg1, int arg2){
       super(arg1) ;
  }
}
```

File2:

```
public class B{
   public B(int arg1){
       super(arg1) ;
  }
  public int getMethod() { return 100;}
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If `getMethod()` can be made static, do that. If it can't, that implies it depends on the state of `this`, which is invalid before construction is complete.

Comment: What is the parent class for B?

Answer (score 2):

So many error here.

- What is the return type of `getMethod` in class B?
- Why do you call super(arg1) in class B? Have you ever defined the parent class of class B?
- Where is the definition of `class_C`?

You'd better provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your question.

Comment: I assume `class_C` is not an `int` ;)

Answer (score 1):

In java, the constructor must be called firstly. In your code, the getMethod in the B class is called before its' constructor is called.
If this was allowed in java, it would messed up it's initialization.